# Is this gas in thermodynamic equilibrium?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, equilibrium

Please consider the following graph of molar volume as a function of pressure for a fixed volume.

[image: Molar Volume against Pressure]

Can we say whether this system under thermodynamic equilibrium or not?

*Update* Thinking about this some more, the molar density vs pressure graph may be useful too.

[image: Molar Density vs Pressure]

Is this gas in thermodynamic equilibrium?

Comment: This is not a homework question. I got my BSc in Chemistry 20 years ago. I have not been working in a Chemistry related field since 2004 and somebody showed this to me to ask what I thought, being somewhat rusty I want to cross check with others

Comment: Did you really mean "for a fixed volume," or did you mean "for a fixed temperature?"  For a fixed volume, molar volume does not change if the number of moles does not change.

Comment: The volume within which the measurement is taken is of fixed size. The temperature and quantity/pressure vary. Think of this as taking a fixed volume sample and measuring the sample's temperature and pressure. The gas is a mixture and well mixed.

Comment: If that's the case then the molar density must be constant.  It is just the mass of gas (which doesn't change) divided by the volume of the container (which also doesn't change).

Comment: the mass of gas is changing as there is less gas at the lower temp & pressure

Comment: Where is the gas (i.e., matter)  going to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39509/discussion-between-stephen-connolly-and-chester-miller).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "equilibrium" is a good word to use in your question.  We have no way of knowing if the gas is at equilibrium from the data you present.  A highly non-ideal gas that was exploding might give the same relationship.  A gas undergoing a rapid unimolecular reaction wouldn't really be at a true chemical equilibrium but could behave as an ideal gas from a pressure / temperature standpoint.

Did you really mean to ask if the gas was **ideal**?  An ideal gas follows $PV = nRT$, which can be re-written in several ways:

- molar density $\frac{n}{V}$ as a function of pressure $P$: $$\frac{n}{V} = \frac{1}{RT}\;P$$, which is the equation of a straight line through the origin (bottom graph).
- molar volume $\frac{V}{n}$ as a function of pressure $P$:  $$\frac{V}{n} = RT \frac{1}{P}$$, which is the equation of a hyperbola (top graph).

Your data is consistent with the gas being ideal (and isothermal).

Comment: So each sample represents a distinct fixed volume sampling from the test environment. The sample is returned after measurement. Some persons have hypothesised that the system is not equilibrated during the experiment (and argue that in other cases there is external energy being absorbed by the system at certain pressures). I am seeing - instead - what could be a phase change for a portion of the gas from monomolecular to dimolecular, but this theory can only be valid if the system itself is under Thermodynamic Equilibrium

Answer (score 0):

We expect pV = constant for equilibrium (ideal gas law aka virial expansion to 1st order). Given this, doubling the pressure should halve the volume. Eyeballing the data points at 0.25 and 0.5 atm suggests such a relationship.

Comment: Yes, that is my rusty opinion too. And in fact if we look at the Molar Density (mol/L) instead of the Molar Volume (L/mol) we get - to my rusty eyes - something that looks suspiciously like a straight line. That kind of says TE to me. In other words this is **necessary** but is this **sufficient** to declare thermodynamic equilibrium?